# EJB Exception - An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using indirection that had a null Session.

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, ejb-3.0

This is not a new exception. I went through lot of forum posts in stack overflow and understand why this is happening. But I need help in resolving my issue.

I have two entity beans Equipment class and Equipment.  Following is the code.

```
public class EquipmentClass implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "class_name")
    private String className;
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "equipmentClass")
    private Collection<Equipment> equipmentCollection;

    // getter and setter methods
 } 


public class Equipment implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createdOn;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "updated_on")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedOn;
    @JoinColumn(name = "equipment_class", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private EquipmentClass equipmentClass;

    // setter and getter methods 

}
```

During adding an equipment, I set equipment class and persist it using `equipmentFacade.create(equipment);`  ( which persist the entity )

```
  EquipmentClass ec = equipment.getEquipmentClass();   
 >>> ec.getEquipmentCollection().add(equipment); << 
  equipmentClassFacade.edit(ec);
```

I get exception in the marked ( >> < )  line above.

As explained [here](http://itechnicalvault.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/java-ejb-exception-while-trying-to.html) , I tried to do `ec.getEquipmentCollection().size();`. But I get exception there.

How should I proceed ?  Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Need the `equipmentFacade.create` method content. Imho it's just a pb of missing persistence context at method invocation.

Comment: getEntityManager().persist(entity); This is exactly inside the create method.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that if you add `equipment.getEquipmentClass().getEquipmentCollection().size()` after the retrieval of `equipment` instance it will solve your problem. 
The fact is probably that the persitence context is not reachable any more at the place where you call getEquipmentCollection(), but i need additional information on your context to help you (ejb, transaction context etc...).
 Can you access the entityManager instance at the place where the exception is thrown ?

Comment: I actually solved the problem. You answer did help me to resolve this.  What I did was to instead of retrieving equipment class object from `equipment.getEquipmentClass();`  , I used `equipmentClassFacade.find(equipment.getEquipmentClass().getId());` This helped me to get the current persistent object of equipment class. Then I simply used `ec.getEquipmentCollection().add(equipment ); `     to add the object. Thank you so much for the reply.